# Wrap STDIN with characters

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line

I would like to turn `"{something: here}"` into `"[{something: here}]"`

For example:

```
$ echo "{something: here}" | magic_command
$ [{something: here}]
```

I want to do it all as part of a bash one liner using STDIN.

Seems simple enough. Any ideas? I'm drawing a blank :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add one pair of brackets around everything:

```
echo "{something: here}" | echo "[$(cat)]"
```

Surround each line separately:

```
echo "{something: here}" | awk '{print "[" $0 "]"}'
```

Comment: @john , i didn't know i could use cat to Copy standard input to standard output. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could try it with sed:

```
echo "{something: here}" | sed 's/\(.*\)/[\1]/'
```

Answer (score 1):

in bash:

```
var="{something: here}"; 
printf "[%s]\n"  "$var"
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out printf. With printf it's easier to write readable bash code.